# std::function vs std::function& as a function argument

Tags: c++, c++11

consider the three functions below,

```
func1(std::function<size_t(...) > f, ...);
func2(std::function<size_t(...) >& f );
func3(const std::function<size_t(...)> &f);
```

For any other type of argument passing by value/copy-constructor, passing by reference and passing by const reference have a clear context and their use cases are well known.

For the case of `function<>` objects, would e.g. passing by const reference save time (from e.g. calling potential copy constructor) or space (no need to pass a whole function object to the stack)? How big is a function object in the first place to make it worth passing passing by const reference? my guess would be that it would roughly be the size of a pointer - is this correct?

Comment: I've always gotten the impression that `std::function` is actually pretty heavy-weight. It has to be able to contain a class instance for member function pointers, for example. And it could potentially be wrapping a bind expression or lambda with captured variables, which obviously need to store extra state that would need to be copied (unless it was heap allocated, I suppose).

Comment: No: A function object (eg. holding a lambda) might be quite expensive to copy.

Comment: @Cameron: It depends on what type of function object it wraps, and how it's implemented. If it wraps a small (or even empty) object, and is optimised not to dynamically allocate it, then it can be very lightweight.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take gcc 4.9 and check:

```
cout << sizeof(int(*)(double, double)) << endl;
cout << sizeof(function<int(double, double)>) << endl;
```

outputs:

```
8
32
```

Size of the callable is, of course, bigger than the pointer size, and you might benefit from passing it by const reference. That is a good idea, however, only if you can guarantee that the object (regardless of it begin an `std::function<>` or not) you pass by const reference lives as long as you're intending to use it.

Answer (score 1):

> For the case of `function<>` objects, would e.g. passing by const reference save time (from e.g. calling potential copy constructor) or space (no need to pass a whole function object to the stack)?

Maybe. You'd have to measure it.

> How big is a function object in the first place to make it worth passing passing by const reference?

It depends on the implementation. You'd have to measure it.

> my guess would be that it would roughly be the size of a pointer - is this correct?

Implementations are encouraged to use a "small object optimisation", so that a small function object is stored inside the `function` object, rather than dynamically allocated. In that case it will be the size of (or slightly larger than) that object. Otherwise, it would be the size of (or slightly larger than) a pointer to the dynamic object.